# Getting file size from S3 download

Tags: php

So I have files stored on Amazon S3. My customers download these files from our website, they click download and it sends the info to our download.php page (the customers don't see this page), but there it uses PHP to get the file name and path (code below). But the issue we have is that it's not telling the browser the file size, so when the customer is downloading they see "remaining time unknown". How can I make it so that the download.php page can get that information and pass it alone?

```
<?php

$file_path = "http://subliminalsuccess.s3.amazonaws.com/";
$file_name = $_GET['download'];
$file = file_get_contents('$file_name');

header('application/force-download');
header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');

$pos = strpos($file_name, "http");

if ($pos !== false && $pos == 0)
{
readfile($file_name);
} else readfile($file_path.$file_name);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's very easy. Look, when you do file_get_contents(), you can get your file size with strlen(). Then you send Content-Length header in the response.

```
<?php

$file_path = 'http://subliminalsuccess.s3.amazonaws.com/';
$file      = trim($_GET['download']);
$file_name = $file_path.$file;

$file_contents = file_get_contents($file_name)
    OR die('Cannot get the file: '.$file);

header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($file_contents));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');

echo $file;
```

BTW, there're so many mistakes in your code. For example, you read files twice, one time with file_get_contents() and second time with readfile(). $file_name variable doesn't have URI. file_get_contents('$file_name') is also wrong.

Also, you don't check your incoming URLs, but just readfile() it which is not nice as someone might pass any URLs to your script...

Comment: thank you for your help. i know very little about PHP and i didnt actually write the code, but no one here was able to figure this out so i was tasked with it. however, when i use the code you pasted above, it actually thinks the file size is 50 bytes, when its actually an MP3 thats more likely 300+ MB or larger.

Comment: Interesting... I don't know why. Are you sure this is the right file? Another option for you is usage of http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/. You can get file via API, grab Content-Length from response and put it the way I showed you.

Comment: its def the right file because if i go back to our original code (not shown), it downloads perfect, just doesnt show time remaining and file size. im going to check out that API link now. Thank you for your help, its much appreciated.